# Can not run MVC Core project When I Publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC Core Project(VS 2017) with SQL Server Data Base. My project works correctly in Local IIS with my real Host SQL Server. But when I publish my project to real host, the project does not work. Also I tested a simple project(with out database) in real host that it works correctly. I think I have a problem in connection string. what should I do to solve this problem? I will be tankful for your helps. 
here are my some codes:

DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private static bool _Created = false;
    public DataContext()
    {
        if (!_Created)
        {
            _Created = true;
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server = sheva.sepantahost.com;Persist Security Info = False; User ID = hbyby11847; Password = N*w23K+nd5; Initial Catalog = hbyby11847_sheva;  ");

    }
```

Web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\News_SourceIran.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[my project solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V0ld.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The application will connect to the database using the identity of the application pool that your IIS website is using. In IIS manager, look at what account that is being used and give that account appropriate permissions in the database.

The exception should also include the account it’s using when trying to connect.